# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'getStreetViewPanoramaAsync' crashes the app

Tags: java, android, maps, google-street-view

I am trying to use Google's StreetView Image API in my app and use it withing a FragmentPageAdapter. I used the streetview api within a single activity and it was working fine but when I tried 'switched' to a 3 fragment fragmentPagerAdapter as soon as I tap on the StreetViewPanoramaFragment fragment the app crashes with the followig:

```
Theme: themes:{}
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
at xdesign.georgi.prototyping_espc_streetview.fragments.StreetViewFragment.onCreateView(StreetViewFragment.java:38)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:535)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
at xdesign.georgi.prototyping_espc_streetview.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:94)
```

This is my "StreetViewFragment"

```
public class StreetViewFragment extends Fragment implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {
private StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

//Overriden method onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment = (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
    streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);
    //Returning the layout file after inflating
    //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.street_virew_fragment_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama) {
    streetViewPanorama.setPosition(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689));
}
}
```

'street_virew_fragment_layout'xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment"
    android:id="@+id/streetviewpanorama"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: override `onViewCreated`, and move those two lines there

Comment: @Blackbelt Thank you for your suggestion but the result is the same as before - I am getting the same NPE :/

Comment: use getChildFragmentManager instead of  getActivity().getFragmentManager()

Comment: @Blackbelt found it! in my fragment XML I was using the Support version of the StreetViewPanoramaFragment. But Without your suggestion it would have crashed anyway so thank you! Could you add your suggestion as an answer please so I can accept it :)

Comment: no worries. The question is already closed.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you again! :) Have a good one! :)